# Migration MyFaces 1.2.6 to 2.0.0 WebSphere

Tags: jsf, runtime-error, websphere, myfaces

I’m currently in the middle of migrating an app from in WAS 6.1 using MyFaces 1.2.6 with JRE 1.5 compliance to WAS 8.5 using MyFaces 2.0.0 with JRE 1.6 compliance.

The app installs ok but the home screen never loads. The log shows that the global constants are loaded but no other activity or error is visible. The node shows some errors:

```
[14/05/20 01:58:35:815 COT] 00000044 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextDestroyed SRVE0285E: Exception caught while destroying context: {0}
                                 org.apache.commons.discovery.DiscoveryException: Class com.ibm.ws.jsf.config.annotation.WebSphereLifecycleProviderFactory does not implement org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.LifecycleProviderFactory

[14/05/20 21:44:01:807 COT] 000000e8 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextDestroyed SRVE0285E: Exception caught while destroying context: {0}
                                 org.apache.commons.discovery.DiscoveryException: Class com.ibm.ws.jsf.config.annotation.WebSphereLifecycleProviderFactory does not implement org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.LifecycleProviderFactory

[14/05/20 22:15:47:946 COT] 000000e1 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0204I: Application: GAA_ADM_DES  Application build level: Unknown
[14/05/20 22:15:48:123 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.OutputFormatTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:128 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.CommandButtonTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:133 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.InputTextTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:137 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.FormTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:139 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.ActionListenerTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:147 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.MessageTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:150 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alignet.sps.action.ServiceValidatorAction

[14/05/20 22:15:48:153 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.GraphicImageTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:158 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.ValidateDoubleRangeTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:161 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.InputSecretTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:164 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.ConvertDateTimeTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:166 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.OutputLabelTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:168 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.SelectOneListboxTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:171 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.SelectManyCheckboxTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:174 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.SelectItemsTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:176 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.ColumnTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:179 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.ValidateLengthTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:183 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.ConvertNumberTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:187 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.SelectItemTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:191 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.ViewTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:194 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.SubviewTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:200 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.SelectOneRadioTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:205 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.ValueChangeListenerTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:212 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.alignet.sps.action.vf.FilevfeAction

[14/05/20 22:15:48:214 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.CommandLinkTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:218 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener

[14/05/20 22:15:48:220 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.MessagesTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:224 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.ValidateLongRangeTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:227 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.PanelGroupTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:230 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.SelectManyMenuTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:232 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.SelectOneMenuTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:235 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.VerbatimTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:243 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.SelectBooleanCheckboxTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:247 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.DataTableTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:249 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.OutputTextTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:255 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.SelectManyListboxTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:257 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.LoadBundleTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:260 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.ParameterTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:263 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.OutputLinkTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:265 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.PanelGridTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:268 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.InputTextareaTag

[14/05/20 22:15:48:274 COT] 000000e1 annotation    W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.annotation.WASAnnotationHelper collectClasses SRVE8000W: Skipped class that failed to initialize for annotation scanning.
                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.InputHiddenTag

[14/05/20 22:15:49:684 COT] 000000e1 jsp           E com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TldParser logParseErrorMessage Failed to parse Tag Library [/WEB-INF/html_basic.tld]: JSPG0236E: The JSP container failed to load the TagLibraryValidator class [com.sun.faces.taglib.html_basic.HtmlBasicValidator]
[14/05/20 22:15:49:690 COT] 000000e1 jsp           E com.ibm.ws.jsp.taglib.TldParser logParseErrorMessage Failed to parse Tag Library [/WEB-INF/jsf_core.tld]: JSPG0236E: The JSP container failed to load the TagLibraryValidator class [com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.CoreValidator]
```

Comment: Tried posting the error in a search engine? Tried contacting ibm for commercial support? Tried a clean buid? Checked for old jars in your project?

Comment: do you still have a facelets jar in your project? If so, remove it. JSF2 has this 'embedded'

Comment: Your webapp has JSF libraries bundled which conflicts with server's own JSF libraries. Normally, when the server already provides JSF libraries, then you should not supply them along with the webapp, else you need to tell the server to disable its JSF libraries.

Comment: Finished cleaning the project and removed the JSF libraries. Couldn’t get rid of jsf-facelets-1.1.11.jar because it caused errors with missing classes if not present. The two first exceptions listed previously are gone but the rest are still showing in the logs.

Comment: Here is the list of the jars contained inside te ear file:

alg-afs-xsd-tx-1.0.jar
alg-ajax4jsf-1.0.jar
alg-eventLog-1.0.jar
alg-hikm-1.0.jar
alg-PoolManager-1.0.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
asm-1.5.3.jar
asm-attrs-1.5.3.jar
bemail-jdk14-1.38.jar
bemail-jdk14-138.jar
bcprov-jdk14-1.38.jar
bcprov-jdk14-138.jar
bcprov-jdk15-1.43.jar
bctsp-jdk14-1.38.jar
cglib-2.1_3.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar

Comment: commons-discovery-0.4.jar
commons-email-1.1.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
commons-io-1.4.jar
commons-lang-2.1.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
db2-java-8.1.jar
db2-jcc_FP4-9.7.jar
db2-jcc-license-cisuz-8.1.jar
db2-jcc-license-cu_FP4-9.7.jar
displaytag-export-poi-1.1.jar
om4j-1.6.1.jar
ehcache-1.2.3.jar
ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar
el-api-2.2.jar
el-ri-1.0.jar
hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar
hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.0.0.ga.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-3.3.1.ga.jar
hibernate-validator-3.0.0.GA.jar

Comment: commons-el-1.0.jar
httpclient-4.1.1.jar
httpcore-4.1.jar
itext-2.1.7.jar
jasperreports-3.7.2.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.1.jar
jcommon-1.0.15.jar
jsf-facelets-1.1.11.jar
jsr173_api-1.0.jar
jstl-1.1.0.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
mail-1.4.jar
oro-2.0.8.jar
owasp-esapi-1.4.jar
poi-3.5-FINAL.jar
shale-core-1.0.5.jar
shale-validator-1.0.5.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
standard-1.1.2.jar
tomahawk20-1.1.10.jar
xbean_xpath-2.2.0.jar
xercesimpl-2.6.2.jar
xmibeans-qname-2.5.0.jar
xmibeans-xmlpublic-2.3.0.jar
xml-resolver-1.1.jar